# Random Number Generating in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers, generator

I am new to programming and have just started to learn about arrays and was doing just fine until I got to an array that stores random numbers inside of it. The line of code below is the one that baffles me the most.

```
for (int roll = 1; roll <=6000000; roll++)
     ++frequency[1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(6)];
```

Before this I imported the Random class and made a new object named randomNumbers as well as declared the variable frequency as an array with 7 integers. The book I am reading tells me that this line above rolls a die 6 million times and uses the die value as frequency index.

I understand that this is going through in iteration 6 million times were it does what it says in the body each time, however I do not see in the body where it sets any variable equal to a random number. I think the biggest thing I am missing is what it means to increment the frequency[] because I understand that within the brackets there is a random number between 1 and 6 being added to 1. So therefore the six million iterations should pass by frequency[1] through frequency[7] if it chance to happen, yet even though it passes them by I do not see how it sets anything equal to those arrays.

Can someone please explain this line of code to me step by step barney style? I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: `++something` is the same as  `something = something + 1`, if that's what you ask

Comment: (FWIW: array elements are considered - and work as - variables in Java. Thus the code is effectively `++i` for some discretely chosen variable.)

Comment: Also note that in Java when you create an array like `int[] frequency = new int[7];`, all elements are automatically initialized with zeroes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That routine could be broken down into this

```
for (int roll = 1; roll <=6000000; roll++) {
    int the_random_number = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(6);
    frequency[the_random_number] = frequency[the_random_number] + 1;
}
```

The code `randomNumbers.nextInt(6)`  returns a number between 0 and 5. For example, if it returns 3, then 1 is added so `the_random_number` becomes 4. After that you increase the frequency occurence of 4 by 1 and store it in the `frequency` array (`frequency[4] = frequency[4] + 1;`).

Comment: Thanks a bunch after reading over your comment I now understand that every iteration adds 1 to a random part of the array, not giving the array a random number per say. Effectively if I add up all the results I should have a total of 6 million.

Answer (score 3):

`randomNumbers.nextInt(6)` generates a number from 0-5; adding one makes it 1-6. The `++` increments the value in the results array corresponding to the chosen number.

You should have an array with approximately 1 million in each if the random number distribution is even.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use these sample as your reference:
import java.util.Random;

/** Generate 10 random integers in the range 0..99. */
public final class RandomInteger {

public static final void main(String... aArgs){
log("Generating 10 random integers in range 0..99.");

//note a single Random object is reused here
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
  log("Generated : " + randomInt);
}

log("Done.");
}

private static void log(String aMessage){
System.out.println(aMessage);
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also try [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math) library's [RandomDataGenerator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html) to generate random numbers.

> The Commons Math random package includes utilities for
>
> generating random numbers generating random vectors generating random
>   strings generating cryptographically secure sequences of random
>   numbers or strings generating random samples and permutations
>   analyzing distributions of values in an input file and generating
>   values "like" the values in the file generating data for grouped
>   frequency distributions or histograms

Example

```
RandomDataGenerator randomData = new RandomDataGenerator(); 
randomData.reSeedSecure(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    value = randomData.nextSecureLong(1, 1000000);
}
```